# Meaning of a frat boy on a road trip

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

I'm struggling with a phrase and need help with that, it's from the book ***Born to Run*** by Christopher McDougall (Random House, 2018):

> There were other races out there and other Tarahumara runners, and it wasn’t long before Fisher had regrouped and was careening from mayhem to mayhem like a frat boy on a road trip.

My main problem is with last 5 word: *like a frat boy on a road trip*. I know that "frat" probably refers to Fraternity, but I couldn't figure out how can it be related to the topic in the book.

Comment: The mental image is of a slightly drunken college student taking a holiday to, say, visit California from Missouri, stopping for misadventures along the way.

Comment: It's a simile - I suppose you are aware of the meaning and general demeanour of a frat boy? If not, HotLick's comment should enlighten you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A college *[fraternity](https://people.howstuffworks.com/fraternity.htm)* is a type of student society in the U.S., Canada, and the Philippines. There are many different kinds of fraternities but in general usage, the term almost always refers to so-called *social* fraternities (women-only fraternities are commonly known as *sororities*). There is no direct equivalent in British universities, although they are somewhat analogous to the *[studentverbindung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Studentenverbindung)* on the Continent.

A *[frat boy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/frat-boy)* is a disparaging term for a member of a social fraternity—very few members I know would ever describe themselves as such. It isn't a single stereotype: it takes on whatever negative behavior or attitudes someone wants to project in the moment; there are [any number of cliché frat boys](https://brobible.com/college/article/10-types-of-frat-bros/). That said, the membership demographic is cavorting young males, so the image will most often include some element of rowdiness, cockiness, or drunkenness. As Cambridge puts it,

> *US, informal, often disapproving* ​
>   a young man who belongs to a college fraternity, and who behaves in the noisy or silly way that is thought to be typical of fraternity members

A *road trip*, broadly, is any relatively long journey driving in a private vehicle. For example, a school sports team might take a bus on a road trip to compete against a team several hours' drive away. But in the U.S., where distances are long and the cost to purchase and fuel an automobile is relatively cheap, it is a cultural touchstone. Disparate films like *[National Lampoon's Vacation](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085995/)*, *[Thelma & Louise](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0103074/)*, *[Almost Famous](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181875/)*, *[Easy Rider](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0064276/)*, and *[The Muppet Movie](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079588/)* are all organized around the conceit of a road trip, in which the main characters encounter various characters and adventures on their way to some destination.

Given that context, the image of

> careening from mayhem to mayhem like a frat boy on a road trip

should be clear: Fisher is trying to advance, but encounters chaotic situation after chaotic situation, in the same way a loud, overconfident, and slightly buzzed young man might get into when stopping for the night on a road trip.

For some over-the-top imagery of frat boys on a road trip, consult the 1978 film *[National Lampoon's Animal House](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0077975/)* (keeping in mind that much of the humor is, by modern standards, "problematic").

Comment: Wow thank you so much for such complete answer, I will watch the movies you mentioned.